Evaluating $\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\left(\log\left(t^2+\frac1{t^2}\right)\right)^{-1}\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{\sin^25x}{x}dx\right)$

The value of
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left\{\left[\log\left(t^2+\frac1{t^2}\right)\right]^{-1}\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(5x\right)}{x}\,{\rm d}x\right\} $$
is ______ (rounded off to two decimal places).

The limit of this problem is $1/4$.
I tried to use l'hopital rule and differentiate the integral and the function of log, but the limit doesn't exist after the differentiation. How can we solve it???

Please type out the problem: You are very unlikely to receive an answer if the question is left as an image.

Are you sure the limit is $1/4$? Because I am getting something involving $\pi$.

You can just replace $\ln(t^2+1/t^2)$ with $\ln(t^2)=2\ln(t),$ since $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\ln (t^2+1/t^2)}{\ln (t^2)}=1.$$ Then the application of L'Hopital is a little easier.

But then L'Hopital gives a non-conclusive answer, since it gives $\lim \sin(5\pi t),$ I think.

@ThomasAndrews when i am putting a large value of t the limit approachs toward 1/4, this question was asked in a iit exam, their is some concept for non conclusive result of lhopital

@sudeep5221 this question was asked in iit jam 2024 math paper,

Consider $\int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\cos^2(5x)}{x} dx$ and show that it has the same growth behavior as $\int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x} dx$ (that is, their quotient converges to 1). Then we can simply consider the integral $$\frac{1}{2} \int_1^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5t) +\cos^2(5t)}{x} dx = \frac{1}{2} \ln(\pi t)$$ instead of the original integral

@Pengin  you are quite intelligent, thanks.. how to think like you?????lol

@Pengin You can put it as an answer.

This essentially boils down to showing that the integral $\int_a^t\frac{\cos x} {x} , dx$ converges as $t\to\infty$. If this came up in JEE then the only option is to assume this fact based on memory. I doubt if improper integrals and their convergence are part of the syllabus for JEE.

Consider $\int_1^ {\pi t} \frac{\cos^2(5x)}{x} dx$. Then this integral has the same growth behavior as $\int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x} dx$ (that is, their quotient converges to 1; you can show this for example by shifting the integral). In particular, it has the same growth as
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_1  ^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x) + \cos^2(5x)}{x} dx = \frac{1}{2} \ln(\pi t).$$
So we obtain
$$ \lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x}dx}{\ln(t^2+t^{-2})} = \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2} \ln(\pi t)}{2\ln(t)} = \frac14 .$$
Edit: We have
\begin{align*}
\left | \int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\cos^2(5x)}{x} dx - \int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x} dx \right | &=\Bigg | \int_{1-\pi/10} ^{\pi t -\pi/10} \underbrace{\frac{\cos^2(5(x+\pi/10))}{x+\pi/10}}_{=\frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x+\pi/10}} dx - \int_1 ^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x} dx \Bigg | \\
&\leq \frac{\pi}{10}\int_1^{\pi t} \frac{1}{x(x+\pi/10)} dx + \int_{1-\pi/10} ^1 \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x+\pi/10}dx \\
&\quad \, + \int_{\pi t - \pi/10}^{\pi t} \frac{\sin^2(5x)}{x} dx \leq C < \infty.
\end{align*}
So the two integrals differ only by at most a constant term and their sum grows logarithmically. Thus they both divergece and they have the same growth behavior.

It would be great if you can show that the ratio of the integrals approaches $1$. I feel that it requires in advance to know that these integrals diverge to $\infty $ in order to show the ratio tends to $1$.

@ParamanandSingh I edited my answer, all we need is that their difference is bounded and their sum diverges.

Nice proof. I had already up voted so can't do anything more right now.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\lim_{t\to\infty}\braces{\bracks{\ln\pars{t^{2} +
{1 \over t^{2}}}}^{-1}
\int_{1}^{\pi t}{\sin^{2}\pars{5x} \over x}\,\dd x}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{t\to\infty}\braces{{1 \over \ln\pars{t^{2}}}
\int_{10}^{10\pi t}{\bracks{\rule{0pt}{4mm}1 - \cos\pars{x}}/2 \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 2}\times{1 \over 2}\lim_{t\to\infty}\braces{{1 \over \ln\pars{t}}
\bracks{\ln\pars{\pi t} + \on{Ci}\pars{10} - \on{Ci}\pars{10\pi t}\rule{0pt}{5mm}}}
\end{align}
where $\on{Ci}$ is the Cosine Integral Function.
$\ds{\on{Ci}\pars{10}}$ is a finite number $\ds{\rm i.e. \approx -0.04546}$.
In addition,  $\ds{\on{Ci}\pars{10\pi t}
\sr{{\rm as}\ t\ \to\ \infty}{\sim} \sin\pars{10\pi t}/\pars{10\pi t}}$. See here.
Therefore,
$$
\color{#44f}{\lim_{t\to\infty}\braces{\bracks{\ln\pars{t^{2} +
{1 \over t^{2}}}}^{-1}
\int_{1}^{\pi t}{\sin^{2}\pars{5x} \over x}\,\dd x}}
= \bbx{\color{#44f}{1 \over 4}}
$$

I have the strange feeling that we could change $5$ by any positive integer, the limit would be the same. Did you look at the asymptotics ? Cheers

@ClaudeLeibovici: you are correct in your observation. Essentially this is about the convergence of cosine integral.

Asssuming that $k$ and $t$ are both positive integers
$$\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{\sin ^2(k x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} (\text{Ci}(2 k)-\text{Ci}(2 k \pi  t)+\log (\pi  t))$$ Expanded as series, the numerator is then
$$\frac{1}{2}\log(t)+ \frac{1}{2} (\text{Ci}(2 k)+\log (\pi ))+\frac{1}{8 \pi ^2 k^2 t^2}-\frac{3}{16 \pi ^4 k^4
   t^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)$$
Concerning the denominator
$$\log \left(t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)=2\log(t)+\frac 1 {t^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)$$
Long division to make the expression
$$\frac 14+\frac{\text{Ci}(2 k)+\log (\pi )}{4 \log (t)}+\frac{1}{16 \pi ^2 k^2 t^2 \log (t)}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^4 \log (t)}\right)$$
$$\frac 1 4\log (\pi )<\frac{\text{Ci}(2 k)+\log (\pi )}{4}<\frac{1}{4} (\text{Ci}(2)+\log (\pi ))$$ with $\text{Ci}(2) =0.422981$.
So the range is quite small.
Trying for $k=$ and $t=1000$, the above truncated series gives
$\color{red}{0.289784032926}11$

thanks you for this answer, but can you please tell me what to do if L'hopital rule is inconclusive. is their some other rule??

@KetanChoudhary. These are Taylor expansions followed by long division. That's all. Cheers :-)
